# Alter properties of specific event "sender" in C++/CLI Windoes Form without switching through them all

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

So, i have this form with a lot of numeric up and down fields, each associated with a label that describes the "unity system" of that field (like, m/s, ft, hp, and so on). I made the labels clickable, so that the unity system of each field can be changed by the user, as well as the appropriate numeric value.

Ok, I cast the clicked label data to determine witch one was clicked and the calculations that have to be done. But now that they are done, I need to change the label text, the one that was clicked, and it could be anyone....

The ideal case, would be something like this:

```
String^ LabelName = ... cast ... sender ... -> name (or some other property to identify the sender, like tabIndex)
```

This is ok, i can cast the sender, identify it, and do the right thing about it. But then, i have to change something about the sender in the form, but I don't know who is it, so i need something like (ideally):

```
this -> LabelName -> Text = .....
```

Obviously, it doesn't work like this. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be something magical about breaking your head around a problem, and then take a sleep and think about something else. Sometimes after that we manage to solve the problem considerably easy.

To be more specific, in the form there are many sets of: a clikable Label containing the unity system, a numericUpDown control with the value, and a hidden textBox with a multiplier, used for the conversions from one system to the other. This is probably not the best arrangement, but it's good for now. So, one solution I found is like this (tb = textbox, nud = numericUpDown):

First, I cast all the relevant controls (and not just a property of them), and to cast the other ones that come right after the clicked label, I use this recently discovered (by me) method: getNextControl(), like this:

```
Label^ thisLabel = safe_cast< Label^ >( sender ); // this is the clicked label
NumericUpDown^ thisNud = safe_cast< NumericUpDown^ >( GetNextControl ( thisLabel, true ) ); // this contains the numeric value, and comes right after the label
TextBox^ thisTb = safe_cast< TextBox^ >( GetNextControl ( thisNud, true ) ); // this is a hidden field one a multiplier for conversions
```

After that, i do all the manipulations needed with the values and other properties. And with the final results and other data in hand, i can (so simply) do like:

```
thisLabel -> Text    = u[ i ];
thisNud   -> Maximum = System::Convert::ToDecimal( maximum / m[ i ] );
thisNud   -> Value   = System::Convert::ToDecimal( vNow  / m[ i ] );
thisTb    -> Text    = System::Convert::ToString ( m[ i ] );
```

I couldn't believe it could work when I decided to try. Almost as the ideal case I mentioned above.
This suposes that the 3 controllers are TabIndexed one after the other....

Hope this will be helpfull to some other newbie as me!

Comment: I'd prefer explicit over implicit information to make sure that the layout and order of controls can be changed without breaking your code. If there are always pairs of nud/label you could create a user control for encapsulation and to know about the relations in advance which would eliminate the need for GetNextControl to group controls logically.